# Assign temp file from cgi and read it in .sh

Tags: perl, variables, csh, cgi

I have `.cgi` file and `.sh` file. The `cgi` is calling the script which is the `.sh` file.
How will assign the tempfile created from `.cgi` and pass it to the `.sh` file?

Example below:

(on my CGI, `$tmpfile` is created)

```perl
#! /usr/local/bin/perl

use CGI qw/:standard :html3/;      
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser); 

my $tmpfile = "$dir/output.$$";
```

(on my .sh file, i want to use the `$tmpfile` from cgi)

```
#! /bin/csh -fb
umask 0

set tmpfile2 = $tmpfile  #not working
```

Comment: does the cgi script work? What's the filename of the `tpmfile` that's created?

Comment: You need to add that variable to the environment before calling your script. I think the Perl way to do that is by adding it to the `%ENV` hash.

Comment: How do you invoke the csh script? Does it get called from perl?

Answer (score 2):

Either, as @muru said, put it into the environment:

`$ENV{tmpfile}= $tmpfile;`

Or pass it to the script as a parameter. This would be much cleaner than littering the environment.